# How to implement Full-Text Search in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm making a Full-Text Search box to find any records that have the data entered in that box. I tried binding the value of the Search box to `@datasource.query.parameters.SearchText`, then assigned

```html
query.keywords = query.parameters.SearchText;
return query.run();
```

I made a button Search to reload the datasource with search value from the Search box but it continues to show all records, not the records that have the value I want:

[Actual Search Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYZBa.png)

Am I missing something? What is the right way to implement this function?

Comment: I believe the keywords functionality did not actually work in App Maker. This may have been discussed in the App Maker User Group and I believe a bug/feature request was filed for this issue as well. From your results I take it that this feature still is not supported in AM. I would suggest checking if you can find the bug report on this or see what the previous discussion was in the AM user group.

Comment: Thank you, It seems that we don't have any working example for this situation. Anyway, do you know any methods to make a Full-Text Search function instead of using `query.keywords`?

Comment: Checking the AM documentation, it stated that the keywords feature needs to be supported by your backend. So if you are using Google Cloud SQL, it would need to be supported by that. If it is supported, then you may need to use a SQL query to make this work. Otherwise, you would need to write a where clause that would include every field that you want to search for your keyword like Field1 contains :SearchText or Field2 contains :SearchText or Field3 contains :SearchText and so on. Or of course you can use the query builder to accomplish this also.

Comment: I enabled some columns as it can do Full-Text Search in database and it appeared in the Indexes list. Is there something equivalent to `MATCH (col1,col2,col3...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])` query in App Maker?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google template called "Partner Management" that has this functionality. It looks like the difference is with the onValueEdit field of the widget. Add this to that field:

```
widget.datasource.query.pageIndex = 1;
widget.datasource.unload();
widget.datasource.load();
updateUrlForContactSearch();
```

Hope that helps.